# Clone Node [golang.org/x/net/html] : Stack overflow

Tags: go, tree

I'm trying to clone/copy a html [Node](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/html#Node) so that I can modify/duplicate it and then inject it back in the main document. The issue is that I'm getting a stack overflow[2]. I assume there is a race condition. It looks like it's due `Parent` and `PrevSibling` fields(based on my blind tests). Any idea why is that and how can I clone it completely(so that it can test positive on reflect.DeepEqual) ?

```
func clone(src *html.Node) *html.Node {
    if src == nil {
        return nil
    }
    n := html.Node{
        Parent:      clone(src.Parent),
        FirstChild:  clone(src.FirstChild),
        LastChild:   clone(src.LastChild),
        PrevSibling: clone(src.PrevSibling),
        NextSibling: clone(src.NextSibling),

        Type:      src.Type,
        DataAtom:  src.DataAtom,
        Data:      src.Data,
        Namespace: src.Namespace,
    }
    for _, v := range n.Attr {
        n.Attr = append(n.Attr, v)
    }
    return &n
}
```

[2]

```
runtime: goroutine stack exceeds 1000000000-byte limit
fatal error: stack overflow

runtime stack:
runtime.throw(0x3495b9, 0xe)
    /Users/x/gosrc/src/runtime/panic.go:566 +0x95
runtime.newstack()
    /Users/x/gosrc/src/runtime/stack.go:1061 +0x416
runtime.morestack()
    /Users/x/gosrc/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:366 +0x7f

goroutine 7 [running]:
runtime.heapBitsSetType(0xc42a0ae5b0, 0x70, 0x68, 0x32e420)
    /Users/x/gosrc/src/runtime/mbitmap.go:867 fp=0xc4402002a8 sp=0xc4402002a0
runtime.mallocgc(0x70, 0x32e420, 0x1, 0x0)
    /Users/x/gosrc/src/runtime/malloc.go:690 +0x5ba fp=0xc440200348 sp=0xc4402002a8
runtime.newobject(0x32e420, 0x0)
    /Users/x/gosrc/src/runtime/malloc.go:785 +0x38 fp=0xc440200378 sp=0xc440200348
bitbucket.org/x/y/client.clone(0xc420138d20, 0x0)
```

Comment: You could probably use `html.Render` to serialize as string and then re-parse as a new node

Comment: @Gillespie that would be very inefficient

Comment: Did you actually try it or are you just speculating? It might be performant enough for your use case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When deep-cloning a data structure containing pointers *that is not a tree* you need a more sophisticated approach; if you call

```
 n := Node{...
           next:clone(src.next),
           prev:clone(src.prev),
           ...}
```

and your structure has even just two siblings nodes `n1` and `n2` where `n1.next` is `&n2` and `n2.prev` is `&n1` the code will stack overflow (cloning `n1` will call `clone(n2)` for the `next` pointer that in turn will call `clone(n1)` for the `prev` pointer, looping back and forth forever until the call stack explodes).

A solution is to keep a "cache" where when cloning a node you will store the `src→cloned` association, so the clone procedure will be able to return the node in case of recursive structures.

What follows is a full minimal example:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Node struct {
    value      int
    prev, next *Node
}

func clone(n *Node, cache map[*Node]*Node) *Node {
    if n == nil {
        return nil
    }

    if val, ok := cache[n]; ok {
        return val
    }

    val := &Node{}
    cache[n] = val
    val.value = n.value
    val.prev = clone(n.prev, cache)
    val.next = clone(n.next, cache)

    return val
}

func printlist(n *Node) {
    for n != nil {
        println(fmt.Sprintf("address=%p, value=%v, prev=%p, next=%p",
            n, n.value, n.prev, n.next))
        n = n.next
    }
}

func main() {
    n1 := &Node{}
    n2 := &Node{}
    n3 := &Node{}
    n1.value = 100
    n2.value = 200
    n3.value = 300
    n1.next = n2
    n2.prev = n1
    n2.next = n3
    n3.prev = n2

    printlist(n1)

    println("Cloning list")
    c1 := clone(n1, make(map[*Node]*Node))
    printlist(c1)
}
```

Running this program on my machine i get

```
~/x$ go run recstruct.go
address=0xc42000e540, value=100, prev=0x0, next=0xc42000e560
address=0xc42000e560, value=200, prev=0xc42000e540, next=0xc42000e580
address=0xc42000e580, value=300, prev=0xc42000e560, next=0x0
Cloning list
address=0xc42000e5c0, value=100, prev=0x0, next=0xc42000e5e0
address=0xc42000e5e0, value=200, prev=0xc42000e5c0, next=0xc42000e600
address=0xc42000e600, value=300, prev=0xc42000e5e0, next=0x0
~/x$
```

where you can see that the three nodes have been cloned correctly and prev/next are pointing each other in the cloned structure list.

Comment: Make sense. I assume *map[*Node]*Node is an error,  right? (map[*Node]*Node would work just fine)